# DataTables in YUI3 refreshing on every update/change of data

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui, yui3, yui2

I has been playing with **YUI3 3.5pre5 DataTables** and realized a big difference in implementations (from YUI2).

When using `addRow(), modifyRow() and set()`, all the table is reloaded/redrawn/refreshed instead of only the elements affected.

For example when a row is added all the table is redrawn instead of only the new row (like in YUI2).

This is a real problem if you have a lot of data and everything is redrawn because of some cell updated. Or if you need to update the data every x seconds the table will be constantly refreshing making it harder to work with.

I hope I'm doing it wrong and there is way of doing it or a workaround.

Please let me know if there is a way to make the new DataTables behave correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing it wrong; that's the current state of the code.  I'll be optimizing data mutation -> UI in 3.6.0, and like I did during 3.5.0, I'll be maintaining a preview module in gallery that has the latest updates and features.

There were plenty of performance improvements that I wanted to get into 3.5.0 that I just couldn't fit in due to the architecture and feature migration from 3.4.1.

In the mean time, here's a patch that should help: https://gist.github.com/2295032

Note, it's not compatible with nodeFormatters, and may have other edge cases.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!! The patch is definitely helping specially when adding rows. Still when updating a single cell all the row is refreshed. Do you think there will be a full YUI2 like implementation for 3.6.0??

Comment: Isolating to the cell would not capture changes to columns that reference the value from formatters.  Why so important to limit update to just the cell?

Comment: We are developing a stocks financial application where values are updated every second. Inside the table, in each row there are also buttons, select boxes, check-boxes and inputs, where the user can change/update/insert values. If the user is somehow interacting with the data when the row is refreshed/re-drawn he will lose the data in the inputs, 'focus' on select boxes etc, etc. also some events can 'not fire'...
That's why I think is very important to isolate data as much as possible.

Comment: Fair enough.  Good feedback.  I'll keep that in mind when working on the core implementation.  In the mean time, I updated the gist with the start of a cell-specific update model.